# Glassfish access control

Tags: glassfish

I have web service deployed in my system under Glassfish server. When I try to access it from another system using my IP and port number it shows an access control origin error.

I tried to solve this by putting a accesscrossdomain.xml file in my Glassfish docroot folder, but the error still continues.

What can be done to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely running into the default configuration, which disables remote administration by default for security reasons. This means no SSL while logging into the administration console, no admin password, etc.

GlassFish Server has [excellent documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/index.html). For this particular issue, [this section](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2435/gkofe.html#scrolltoc) of the Security Guide should help. Basically, you'll want to run "*asadmin enable-secure-admin*". To learn more about secure admin, read [this section](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2435/gkocp.html#scrolltoc) of the Security Guide.